# How to trigger a script only after a specific URL path with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

i would like to trigger with PHP a JS script basically to change the inlinehmtl only after a specific URL path, basically for site translation purporses. To be more specific, i would like to trigger this JS script:

`document.getElementById("changeme").innerHTML = "Get Started";`

Only when the English (to translate an html element that a WP plugin couldnt access) folder of the site is queried or:

It would be the /en/ (en for english content) folder or example.com/en/ and also example.com/en/products.php  ...etc.

Any ideas, how that PHP script would look like, thanx!

Answer (score 0):

the most proper way to do this seems to be to pass a parameter to PHP script by **POST** or **SESSION** in my opinion.

You can do also verification in JS of your current localization then trigger the script or not

```
<script>

    ...

    if( checkLocations( window.location.href ) )
    {
        //your script here
```

Comment: Would the script be written like this?  
   if( checkLocations( window.location.href("http://crossfitzurriola.com") ) )
    {
      window.alert("Hi);
  
 }  That script is not working if its like that? Any corrections?

Comment: try to check what exactly value of window.location.href is by adding alert( window.location.href) before if statement - I guess there is at least **http://** before so you can just find substring you are looking for in window.location.href